# Does each protractor test need to be in its own spec file for parallelization

Tags: protractor

I hope I am clear in my description of what I am asking for clarification on.

I have taken over protractor automation for the app I am supporting.  Right now the spec files are broken down by functionality (i.e. User_add, User_edit).  Each spec file has multiple tests that run one after the other.

```
describe('Add User', function () {
it('Test 1', function (done) {});
it('Test 2', function (done) {});
it('Test 3', function (done) {});
it('Test 4', function (done) {});
})
```

I need each test to run in parallel through saucelabs.  From what I have been reading I think I am going to have to move each test into its own spec file to be able to get them to run in parallel.  Before we spend the time doing this(we have A LOT of tests and spec files), I wanted to make sure there isn't a better way to do this.

Thank you in advance for your help. 
Christine